# Go to particular cell by finding text in the column EXCEL

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I have sheet A  having text "Babu"
in the sheet b having text "babu" at the 500 th row  in the column B

i want to create a hyperlink in the sheet having babu text ,on clicking that link it should search the particular text in the coulmn b and go to that cell .

i have like this many values in the sheet A

Comment: Instead of creating of hyperlink you can link the cell and go back to source using `ctrl + {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your text in cell A1, in another cell:

```
=HYPERLINK("#"&"SheetB!" & ADDRESS(MATCH(A1,SheetB!B1:B100),2), A1 )
```